# Chancing img source according to the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is something that I didn't understand is about getting attribute of html element I have a small project to develop myself and I have to get img source element it's okey so far but whenever I want to change img source with `data-tablet` or `data-mobil` or `data-web` on wide screen my img source is not chancing.What is my mistake ?

What am I trying to do ?
I have three data- attribute `data-mobil` for `<480px` `data-mobil` for  `<768px` and `data-web` for `>=768px` they attribute will be apply

edit: according to resolution actually

Edit 2: I check `srcset`but this is not the thing that I talking about..my question is chancing image src I mean on dekstop and on mobile or tablet will be different images

[please click to see my project on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/jypEXE)

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(".box img").each(function(){
    var getWeb = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-web");
    var getTablet = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-tablet");
    var getMobil = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-mobil");

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
    }else if ($(window).width() < 480){
     $(this).attr("data-src",getMobil);
    }else if ($(window).width() > 480){
       $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
     }else if($(window).width() > 768)
    {
     $(this).attr("data-src",getWeb);
    }
   });
})
```

```css
.box{
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}
.box img{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.7/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="box">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/18/21/34/cyprus-1990939_960_720.jpg" data-web="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/18/21/34/cyprus-1990939_960_720.jpg" data-tablet="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/31/09/30/raspberry-2023404_960_720.jpg" data-mobil="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/12/ring-nebula-1995076_960_720.jpg" class="lazyload" />
  </div>
  
    
  <div class="box">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/06/orange-1995056_960_720.jpg" data-web="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/06/orange-1995056_960_720.jpg" data-tablet="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/29/12/46/apple-379373_960_720.jpg" data-mobil="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/21/00/29/fruit-1213041_960_720.jpg" class="lazyload" />
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are trying to achieve something in most complex way. since you added css tag to your question you can use media queries easily for your purpose.

Comment: but images will be dynamically and I won't user same picture

Comment: Did you mind the srset attribute ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: yes like it but srset is not supporting all browser we are using ie9 and ie10

Comment: Ok but does IE9 and 10 are running on tablets and mobile ? ;)  a tutorial  (also for other readers ): https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks but I didn't understand how work srcset my image is not appear ? http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/mRjzMg

Comment: I check it but this is not the thing that I talking about..my question is chancing image src I mean on dekstop and on mobile or tablet will be different images :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if conditions are wrong

Conditions should be like

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
   $(this).attr('src', getWeb);
} else if ($(window).width() < 768 && $(window).width() > 480) {
     $(this).attr('src', getTablet);
} else if ($(window).width() < 480) {
     $(this).attr('src', getMobil);
}
```

Edit

Instead of writing such long get function you can write

```
var getWeb = $(this).attr("data-web");
var getTablet = $(this).attr("data-tablet");
var getMobil = $(this).attr("data-mobil");
```

Comment: yes but I guess not only my if conditions maybe my get function is wrong too (I'm trying to learn jquery)

Comment: thanks I have another question too if you are suitable .each is right ? or do  I have to use another way ?

Comment: As long as you are using jquery, .each is best to loop on DOM elements. As per my knowledge, how you have used .each, is the proper way. No issues in it

Comment: function didn't work where is my mistake maybe my each function can be wrong how do I use than if I want to change img with loop ? by the way so thanks

Comment: I don't know, what is going wrong with codepen and pixabay. but when I inspect the img element the attribute is proper as expected. to check this I created simple pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxBJGR